# findstr "^" doesn't work but "^^" does to lookup the beginning lines

Tags: batch-file, findstr

My findstr /c:"^string" works in funny way.
To lookup top of each lines using findstr /r with "^", is there any way to put the same query?  At least, I found where there's variable as file name, /c:"^^abc" picks up properly, but /c:"^abc" doesn't.

```
>type test.txt
 abc
abc
```

```
>type test.bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Myfile=test.txt
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`findstr /n /r /i /c:"^abc" "!Myfile!"`) do (
    echo %%i
)
goto :eof
```

```
>test.bat
1: abc
2:abc
>
```

Only when I put 2 "^"s, i.e /c:"^^abc", then,

```
...
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`findstr /n /r /i /c:"^^abc" "!Myfile!"`) do (
...

>test.bat
2:abc
>
```

Or, when I put %Myfile% instead of !Myfile!, it looks working with c:"^abc".  But, Myfile will vary through each run.  So %variable%, or immediate_value won't work for me.

Is there any ways to put a **Universal** lookup (any switch available?) so that I don't need to check each time I write codes?  This would reduce quite a lot of time to debug.

FYI, Replacing !Myfile! with %%x by putting one more "For" loop works with **Single** "^".  This is the only way I can forget about "^^"against !Myfile! for now.

```
>type test2.bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Myfile=test.txt
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%h in (`dir /a-d /b "!Myfile!"`) do (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`findstr /n /r /i /c:"^abc" "%%h"`) do (
        echo %%i
    )
)
goto :eof
>test2.bat
2:abc
>
```

Comment: Have you tried `findstr`'s `/b` switch (at beginning of line) - it has a complement, you know - /incon... no, no, no - the complement is `/e` for 'at end of line'

Comment: Thank you for your great response.  I need "/r" and delayedexpansion for another purpose.  /nrib /c:"abc Additional_Regular_Expression" solves all the problems.